# adding check box in the jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

i am using swings for creating the desktop application . i have created  the functionality which provided the data from the database and insert that  into the Jtable  .now i want to use provide the additional facility that include the additional column with the check box and the a button  to delete that perticuler  column (which is checked ) when the button is clicked .i have used the netbeans and it provide the maximum drag and drop option. i am not able to figure it out that the how and where to insert the instance of the checkbox in the current code for inserting the checkbox for the each and every row . 
For providing the checkbox with the each row do have to generate the multiple instance of the check box

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    java.sql.Connection con = new DBConnection().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String Q;
    Q = "select * from userregister ";
    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement(Q);

        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        String a, b, c, d;
        int x = 0;
     //   DefaultTableModel dt = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox();
        for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
            a = rs.getString(1);
            b = rs.getString(2);
            c = rs.getString(3);
            d = rs.getString(4);
       jTable2.setValueAt(a, i, 0);
       jTable2.setValueAt(b, i, 1);
       jTable2.setValueAt(c, i, 2);
       jTable2.setValueAt(d, i, 3);
     jTable2.setValueAt(, i,4);
        }


   //jTable1.setAutoscrolls(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
  // TODO add your handling code here:
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

this is the methods that insert the data into the table . also i want to know that how do i be able to find out that which check box is checked and how to use the variable to respond the request of the multiple deletes . plz help

Comment: maybe this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391877/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-jtable-swing

Comment: Check out here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/21050379/1686291

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take a look to [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) section of [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.

This `JCheckBox` you're looking for is the default renderer/editor for `Boolean` class. Having said this [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) makes use of [TableModel.getColumnClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29) to decide the proper renderer/editor. If you use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) the implementation of the aforementioned method always return `Object.class` so you would have to override it to return `Boolean.class`. For instance let's say the first column will contain booleans:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }
};
```

It is all well explained in the linked tutorial.

#### Addendum

Another approach is shown in this Q&A: [Checkbox in only one JTable Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931344/checkbox-in-only-one-jtable-cell/21934750#21934750). This is useful when a given column may contain different types of values (booleans, numbers, strings...) so overriding `getColumnClass()` is not feasible. Don't think it's your case but it might be helpful.

---

> also i want to know that how do i be able to find out that which check
>   box is checked and how to use the variable to respond the request of
>   the multiple deletes

Just iterate over the rows asking for the column value (true/false). If it's "selected" (true) then delete it:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    if((Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 0)) {
        // delete the row
     }
}
```

---

#### Off-topic

Database calls are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (a.k.a. EDT) causing the GUI become unresponsive. The EDT is a single and special thread where Swing components creation and update take place. To avoid block this thread consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform database calls in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more in [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) trail.