# JTable how to render different swing objects in the same column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablemodel

I want to render different swing components in the same JTable column. For example, I want to have few different comboboxes, jlabels and jcheckboxes in the same column. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html provides information how to render only one type of combobox per column, however it is not enough.

How can I setup table cell renderer so that it would achieve this functionality?

Comment: Renderer(then the same for Editor) has parameter for column and row, a few times here about

Comment: It seems like I overlooked it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use different editors/renderers in the same column, you can follow the approach described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21934750/1795530) and override `JTable#getCellEditor()` based on the cell (column and row intersection). `JTable#getCellRenderer()` can be overriden if needed as well.

In [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is described the strategy followed by tables to get a renderer/editor so you can take advantage of it to solve your problem.